# SQL CLR - Permission Error on TSQL UDF Even Though User Has Access

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

I am using a context connection in a SQL CLR scalar function. The function builds a dynamic query and then executes it (sourcing the data/logic from various places to build the query).

I can "build" the dynamic string manually and run it in a standard Management Studio window and it runs fine. When that same query is executed via CLR on the context connection I am getting an error.

I debugged the thing and found that the error is due to a permission issue on a TSQL UDF that is being called in the query. The error message produced is:

> EXECUTE permission denied on be.udfDivide

I know I have access to that UDF because it works when I run the query manually - it fails though when run via SQLCLR even though the SQLCLR code should be executing under my context.

The query is effectively:

```sql
select be.udfDivide(sum(Numerator), sum(Denominator))
from Table where <some stuff>
```

The `<some stuff>` is where all the complex logic lives but I assure you it is just a where clause and this CLR function runs millions of times a day successfully when there is no UDF being referenced in the query.

Through some creative query hacking I have been able to confirm that the context connection is being run under the correct user (both `SYSTEM_USER` and `CURRENT_USER`) and I know that user has permissions to the UDF. So it does sound like the breaking in ownership chaining is what is causing this. Just don't know how to fix it yet.

I know I can remove the UDF in this specific case since it is a simple divide (although the UDF handles divide by zero for us) but in the case of more complex UDFs we would like to be able to reference them in the query.

---

The `be.udfDivide` function is provided below, for reference:

```sql
ALTER function [be].[udfDivide](@Numerator float, @Demoninator float,
                                @ValueIfDivideByZero float)
returns float
as
begin
    declare @result float
    if @Demoninator = 0 
        begin set @result = @ValueIfDivideByZero end
    else
        begin set @result = @Numerator / @Demoninator end
    return @result
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on here is not documented anywhere that I could find, but seems to be a requirement of specifying `SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read` in the `SqlFunction` attribute (by default it is set to `None`) when executing queries containing T-SQL Scalar UDFs or Multi-statement TVFs, BUT *only* if the function is *not* schema-bound. Meaning, you can get away with `SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None` if the referenced function is:

- an Inline TVF
- a Scalar UDF, or Multi-statement TVF, that is created using the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option

It makes sense that Inline TVFs have no issue since their definition is pulled into the query in which they are referenced and they are not called as separate objects.

I assume that the reason for requiring "system" data access for non-schema-bound UDFs and Multi-statement TVFs is that system catalog views probably need to be checked at run-time in order to verify that any dependencies still exist and permissions are valid as those cannot be guaranteed to be the same as they originally were due to the lack of schema binding (which prevents certain changes to objects that are dependencies of other objects).

With this in mind, the quickest / most direct fix (which allows for `SystemDataAccess` to remain unspecified or at least set to `None`) would be to add that one option to the UDF as follows:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [be].[udfDivide](@Numerator FLOAT, @Denominator FLOAT,
                                @ValueIfDivideByZero FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- this option helps in a few ways
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result FLOAT;
    IF (@Denominator = 0)
    BEGIN
      SET @Result = @ValueIfDivideByZero;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @Result = (@Numerator / @Denominator);
    END;

    RETURN @Result;
END;
```

**BUT**, if this query runs that often, then you certainly should convert it to an Inline TVF. There is a *huge* performance hit when using UDFs and ITVFs are typically the answer to that. You just need to express the same logic as a single query (use `CASE` for "if-then-else"), and then use it via `CROSS APPLY` rather than in the `SELECT` list, both of which are easy enough.

Here is the same logic as an Inline TVF:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [be].[itvfDivide](@Numerator FLOAT, @Denominator FLOAT,
                                @ValueIfDivideByZero FLOAT)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- not necessary, but still a good idea to use
AS RETURN
   SELECT CASE @Denominator
             WHEN 0 THEN @ValueIfDivideByZero
             ELSE (@Numerator / @Denominator)
          END AS [Result];
GO
```

And here is a simple test:

```sql
SELECT itvf.[Result]
FROM   (VALUES (1, 2, NULL), (3, 0, -5.789), (1.1, 5.67567, -999)
       ) tbl(num, den, dbz)
CROSS APPLY be.itvfDivide(tbl.[num], tbl.[den], tbl.[dbz]) itvf;
```

This ITVF will be *much* faster than the current Scalar UDF :-).

Comment: Wrapping in an `exec` produces the correct result (same result as a non-dynamic query in SSMS). We do have dozens of inline table value functions but this specific case isn't conducive to it. Edited the question to provide the error message.

Comment: quick clarification - this specific use case would only run a dozen or so times a day - other queries without calls to UDFs run millions

Comment: I assume all of these objects are in the same DB? Also, is there any Impersonation being used? The `CREATE FUNCTION` definition, does it include an `EXECUTE AS` clause? Typically it would be `EXECUTE AS CALLER`. Are you logged in as a Windows Login or SQL Server Login? What does the `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` function return while running under the context connection?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - got pulled into some other things. All in the same DB. No `EXECUTE AS` is specified in `CREATE FUNCTION`. Logged in as Windows login. I am `sa` on the server and this will not work for me. `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` returns my user ID when I run the query.

Comment: Setting `EXECUTE AS` in the `CREATE FUNCTION` to any of `CALLER, SELF, OWNER, <USER_NAME>` still produces the error.

Comment: Thanks for all of that additional info. Are you 100% sure that this is a context connection? Sorry, just have to ask ;-). Also, are the T-SQL and SQLCLR UDFs in the same schema? Also, is the generated query doing _anything_ other than a simple `SELECT`? Can you use SQL Server Profiler to capture what is being submitted by the SQLCLR UDF?

Comment: Sure on the context connection. This is the code I am using in the SQLCLR function. `SqlConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");
            connection.Open();` The CLR and TSQL functions are in the same schema within the DB. The CLR code builds a query string dynamically (based on many factors) but the ultimate result is a select statement that aggregates rows from a table - the select statement just has to return a float value is the only requirement.

Comment: Will play with profiler and report back on the results.

Comment: Ok. So you build the query and call `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` or possibly `ExecuteScalar()`? Also, I hope you have a `finally` block that includes `connection.Dispose();` ;-)

Comment: On the profiler, I don't even see the dynamic query in SQLCLR getting executed - just the TSQL select call `select be.udfGetCellValue1(1, 1, '')` which is my SQLCLR wrapper in TSQL. A number of things happen but ultimately a dynamic query gets executed. It works as long as that query does not contain a UDF, just simple sums, counts, averages, etc. As soon as we introduce a UDF into the select statement we get an error. Trying to debug the CLR code now as well - remote debugging leaves a lot to be desired!

Comment: `finally
        {
            //need to clean up resources! from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/105841/
            if (connection != null && connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Close(); 
        }`

Comment: `return (double)command.ExecuteScalar();` is what is getting called.

Comment: If you can't see the Dynamic SQL within the SQLCLR UDF being called, then it's getting filtered out somehow, but there's no way that it's not there. I think it's the "SQL:" category that you need. Can you temporarily grant `EXECUTE` on the T-SQL UDF to `[Public]` to eliminate the "who is calling it" thing? Also, I wonder if there is a `DENY` somewhere along the way, but not sure why it would only show up when called from within SQLCLR. Glad you are closing the connection; I've heard good things about the author of that article ;-) (though I now prefer calling `Dispose()`, but `Close` is fine).

Comment: Also, another thing to try: create a new SQLCLR UDF that does nothing but execute the full query that contains the T-SQL UDF. This way we narrow down what is happening. It should be a simple SQL statement that is not being built, just provided.

Comment: Ok. So clicked pretty much every single Profiler event I could find. Ran the query and got back `This statement has attempted to access data whose access is restricted by the assembly.`. I have the following in the decorator: `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]` but perhaps I need `SystemDataAccess` as well? If that is the case I will save you the hassle and I will hit myself.

Comment: No, `SystemDataAccess` is what the method needs in order to select from system objects. I didn't think that the T-SQL UDF was doing anything like that, or I would at least expect a different error message if so. Can you try putting that query that references the T-SQL UDF into its own SQLCLR UDF to isolate what is going on? Still, it is troubling that you aren't seeing it in Profiler. Are you sure that the code in the Assembly within SQL Server is the version for the source code that you are looking at?

Comment: I can see it now in Profiler. I just added `SystemDataAccess` option in the decorator and....it now works. Not sure if something else is now broken - lots of testing to do. In Visual Studio debugger we got the error that we did not have permissions - however Profiler gave us a better error on the assembly doesn't have the necessary permissions, not the user.

Comment: So with `SystemDataAccess=Read` the T-SQL UDF now can be used in a query without causing an error? What is that T-SQL UDF doing? I can run a test or two and then update my answer to be a more accurate and full explanation.

Comment: Correct. udfDivide simply divides 2 numbers and handles divide by zero without throwing an error. Just left the office but will paste the code inside the function tomorrow. We saw this occur on other user defined functions as well.

Comment: This will take a little more investigation, but I am getting closer. I was able to reproduce the error, and then applied the "fix" of `SystemDataAccess = Read` (which _shouldn't_ be required) and it worked. BUT, problem not solved since I then tested with an inline TVF and multi-statement TVF. Put the function back to `SystemDataAccess = None` and they both worked. But then I tried the original UDF and now it works. It might be a metadata issue, but I ran `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL');` but the UDF still works. Odd. I am still looking and will let you know what I find.

Comment: @thomas Answer has been updated. Please turn `SystemDataAccess` back to `None`, then use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` for other UDFs, but for this particular UDF, convert it into an Inline TVF as I provided at the end of my answer. You will be _much_ better off :-). (p.s. I also fixed the misspelled "denominator" ;-). Enjoy   (happy cat) 

Comment: Amazing. Your thorough response and investigation is very much appreciated. I have been able to produce the same results as you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are quite welcome. Interesting issue to investigate, and will go into my up coming project of a website devoted to SQLCLR -- best practices, common errors, resources, etc. :-)